# MySQL upgrade fails on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running (clean install - no upgrade). MySQL is running fine - but I get this error when I try to update MySQL:

```
apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
Checking system database.
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.engine_cost                                  OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.gtid_executed                                OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.server_cost                                  OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slave_master_info                            OK
mysql.slave_relay_log_info                         OK
mysql.slave_worker_info                            OK
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
The sys schema is already up to date (version 1.5.1).
Checking databases.

ALL DATABASES RETURNED OK

Error occurred: Error during call to mysql_check.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 4
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Although it's running, I dont like errors. Do you guys have any idea how to fix this issue?

Running dpkg -l | grep mysql gives:

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql 
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                  4.033-1ubuntu0.1                                     amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient20:amd64             5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-client                       5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              all          MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-client-5.7                   5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.7              5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                       5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
iU  mysql-server                       5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
iF  mysql-server-5.7                   5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.7              5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                              amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  php-mysql                          1:7.0+45+deb.sury.org~xenial+1                       all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php5.6-mysql                       5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1                       amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mysql                       7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1                       amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Thanks

Comment: Try asking the question on super-user or ask-ubuntu.

Comment: Please answer your question

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this myself and I believe it has to do with how the upgrade process stops/starts/restarts MySQL.

Here is my workaround that I do after an attempted upgrade of MySQL fails.

1. Start MySQL normally, typically "service mysql start" as root.
2. As root execute "mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf". Hopefully it should complete with no errors or indicate that MySQL is already upgraded.
3. Edit the file "/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst" with your favorite editor. Around line 320 (depending on version) find the line "mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf || result=$?". Comment that line out (prepend line with '#'), if should look like "#mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf || result=$?". Save the file and exit from the editor.
4. Rerun the upgrade process and it should indicate that MySQL is now upgraded.

At some point I will dig further to see why the "mysql_upgrade ..." invocation fails during the upgrade but not alone from the command line. But I've not gone through a few iterations of upgrades without issue using this method.

Hope this helps.

'Grip

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before, the root cause for this issue was changing the db configuration.
I changed `lower_case_table_names = 1` and set the value to one, and when I tried to upgrade it failed with the error you shared in your question.

To solve it, I simple set the value back to 0, restarted the db, and the upgrade worked well for me.

First edit the config:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

change this line:

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

restart the database

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Then run the upgrade command

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is for upgrading MySQL with "**mysql_secure_installation**" fix.

Had problems with upgrading MySQL Server 5.7 in Ubuntu 16.04 and I finally located my problem. I enabled "mysql_secure_installation" during my first installation that causes the upgrade script to fail due to password creation error (**unsatisfied special character requirement on the automatically generated password in the upgrade script**).

While running 'sudo apt upgrade' or 'sudo apt install -f', the error can be traced using this command:

> tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log

In my case, the log shows:

> [ERROR] 1819  Your password does not satisfy the current policy
>   requirements

To fix this, login to mysql and temporarily disable MySQL's validate password plugin:

> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
>
> mysql> uninstall plugin validate_password;
>
> mysql> exit

make sure to stop the previous upgrade/install and rerun the upgrade/install. Once done, login back to mysql and enable MySQL's validate password plugin;

> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
>
> mysql> install plugin validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';
>
> mysql> exit

Answer (score 0):

always check /var/log/mysqld.log first